# How to create "generative art" on an existing word/pdf document?

Tags: processing, processing.js, generative-art

I am new to processing and using processing.js to create some 'generative art'. I want to know if there are any references, tools, codes, scripts (processing.js based) which allow us to create these patterns on the top/background of an existing word/pdf document?

Currently, I can create these patterns on the top of an image and can also set the attributes, like opacity.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: try the Processing application, have a look at the samples, there are examples on how to save images and print ready PDF files as well

Answer (score 1):

In Processing 2+ and Processing.js you can load SVG's created by Illustrator and Inkscape into a `PShape` with `loadShape()`. I am not aware of anything that allows you to do this with PDF or Word documents.

If you can find a Java library (Processing 2+) or a Javascript library (Processing.js) that might be a solution.